# Equivalent of Bash's ${myvar:-default} in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

In Bash, I can do something like:

`${VAR1:-default}`

...which means if VAR1 doesn't exist, return "default".

There are lots of these types of operators:[image: Bash parameter expansion examples]

There seem to be numerous examples using `Get-Variable` but nothing particularly succinct. Is there an equivalent in Powershell that I'm missing?

Comment: AFAIK PowerShell doesn't support this kind of parameter expansion. What are you trying to achieve? Do you need this for function parameters or for variables in general?

Comment: FWIW If that's inside a string you use as a template, you can make your own template processing function that behaves just like Bash.

Answer (score 1):

If you need defaults when processing the arguments to your script or function, then yes you can supply them:

```
param (
    [string]$price = 100, 
    [string]$ComputerName = $env:computername,    
    [string]$username = $(throw "-username is required."),
    [string]$password = $( Read-Host -asSecureString "Input password" )
    [switch]$SaveData = $false
)
```

but if you mean defaults when substituting an existing variable into an expression then no, you have to write an expression that gives you the desired value.